# ssh server not accepting public/private keys (Cygwin)

Tags: ssh, cygwin, public-key, private-key

I am trying to connect my computer to a ssh server (running on Windows 7) using public/private keys.

I have generated the keys and used the necessary permissions for files:

```
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 600 authorized_keys
```

and have also added the public key of my computer to the ssh server's authorized_keys file

Now when I try to connect to the ssh server it disconnects and in the log the error I get is:

```
fatal: seteuid 1000: Operation not permitted
```

Edit: Yes I can remotely login with password to ssh server. Another error which I saw was:

```
we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by ssh-server
```

Comment: Whats the remote OS? Are you able to login remotely with a password?

Comment: Please add this information to your question - in a comment it might get lost.

Comment: I was asking for the *remote* OS, not the local one.

Comment: the ssh server (remote) is running on Windows 7

Comment: Hmm - I don't suppose there is anything like a UID in Windows - they use UUIDs.

Comment: The funny thing is the ssh-server (windows 7: running Cygwin) can connect via public keys to my computer (also running a ssh-server: windows 7 Cygwin), but not the other way round.

Comment: Thats no wonder - your local ssh-server runs on linux :-) -- Does your remote ssh-server run under cygwin? (no experience with ssh-servers under windows here)